# Plot validation curve for class-weight in sklearn

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to plot validation curve for class weight. In fact, I tired the following code to do this task:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold, validation_curve, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_validation_curve(param_range, train_scores, test_scores, title, alpha=0.1):
    train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(param_range, train_mean, label='train score', color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, train_mean + train_std,
                     train_mean - train_std, color='blue', alpha=alpha)
    plt.plot(param_range, test_mean, label='test score', color='red', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, test_mean + test_std, test_mean - test_std, color='red', alpha=alpha)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.xlabel('Parameter value')
    plt.ylabel('F-measure')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2, weights=[0.9, 0.1], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0,
                               n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
    st = StandardScaler()

    rg = LogisticRegression(class_weight={0: 1, 1: 6.5}, random_state=42, solver='saga', max_iter=100, n_jobs=-1)

    param_grid = {'clf__C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
                  'clf__class_weight': [{0: 1, 1: 6}, {0: 1, 1: 5.5}]}

    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', st),
                               ('clf', rg)])

    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42)
    rg_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring='f1')
    rg_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))

    param_range2 = [{0: 1, 1: 6}, {0: 1, 1: 4}, {0: 1, 1: 5.5}]

    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
        estimator=rg_cv.best_estimator_, X=X_train, y=y_train, param_name="clf__class_weight", param_range=param_range2,
        cv=cv, scoring="f1", n_jobs=-1)

    plot_validation_curve(param_range2, train_scores, test_scores, title="Validation Curve for class_weight", alpha=0.1)
```

However, this error is reported, which is related to the param_range2 in the last line:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Hello, In the plot, what exactly do you want the x axis to be ?

Comment: @sera. Thanks a lot. Could you please let me know if it is necessary to plot both learning curve and validation curve for our tuned model? Is there a reference article for these two?

Comment: Since the weight for the first class is always 1, it is sufficient and reasonable to plot the curves only for the range of the parameters of the second class. The posted answer seems okay to me. best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to decide what you want to plot on your x-axis. You do a parameter sweep over the different class weights. Since you fixed the weight for the first class to 1 and only modified the weight for class 2, I decided to plot the scores against the weight for class two.

I then sorted the weights in the plot function in ascending order so that you get nicely connected lines.

```
def plot_validation_curve(param_range, train_scores, test_scores, title, alpha=0.1):
    param_range = [x[1] for x in param_range] 
    sort_idx = np.argsort(param_range)
    param_range=np.array(param_range)[sort_idx]
    train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    plt.plot(param_range, train_mean, label='train score', color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, train_mean + train_std,
                     train_mean - train_std, color='blue', alpha=alpha)
    plt.plot(param_range, test_mean, label='test score', color='red', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, test_mean + test_std, test_mean - test_std, color='red', alpha=alpha)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.xlabel('Weight of class 2')
    plt.ylabel('Average values and standard deviation for F1-Score')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot
[image]